# C++ error on atol action

Tags: c++, string

This is the code I used. I usually get a an error called "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'string' was corrupted." I don't know how to un-corrupt the data.is there anything I can do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int result;
    char string[5];
    cout << "Enter a number in 5 digits (type 0's if less than 5 digits): ";
    cin >> string;
    result = atol(string);
    cout << result << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ideally, when using C++ - avoid the using raw char arrays - std::string gives you everything you'll need ... without the memory risks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` has space for 5 chars.

You need an extra space for the \0 terminator.

Either enter 4 digits or change string to a total of 6 chars length.

(Or since you're in C++, find another approach where you don't have to rely on fixed length char buffers)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a buffer overflow as it does not prevent the user from overflowing `string`.

A quick fix is:

```
cin >> std::setw( sizeof string ) >> string;
```

You may want to increase the size of `string` to `6` in order to allow `5` digits to be entered, remembering that C-style strings require a null terminator.

If you use `std::string` instead of a char array then this limitation of needing a preset size goes away.